# React, call a stateless function to organize code, but how to bind this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, bind

Given this react code

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

that executes the function

```
import {onFormSubmit} from '../onFormSubmit'
.....
onSubmit = (e) => {
    // here I have access to "this" thanks to the arrow functions
    e.preventDefault()
    onFormSubmit(this.state.files, this.props)
}
```

Where `onFormSubmit` resides in another file as a stateless function

```
export const onFormSubmit = async (files,props) => {
    this.setState(... // error
}
```

I see that I lose "this" when I'm within the onFormSubmit function, so that there I cannot for example execute a `this.setState`

Then, how can I keep the access of this?

**Option A**, as said in the answers, is to forget the arrows:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    // here I have access to "this" thanks to the arrow functions
    e.preventDefault()
    onFormSubmit.bind(this)(this.state.files, this.props)
}
```

.

```
export async onFormSubmit = function(files,props) {
    this.setState(... // now it works
}
```

**Option B**, to pass `this` as a variable

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    // here I have access to "this" thanks to the arrow functions
    e.preventDefault()
    let self = this
    onFormSubmit(self)
}
```

**Option C**, to redefine `onFormSubmit` as an updater, as said in the answers, but not an option here since the function doesn't only updates the state, for example:

```
export const onFormSubmit = async (files,props) => {
    if (files) {
      ... upload file ... parse file ...
      this.setState({'data': data})
    } else {
      ... fetch file ... concat file ... doesn't update the state
    }
    ... and more calculations
    this.setState({...})
}
```

Comment: The question lacks `onFormSubmit` itself.

Comment: added for clarification

Answer (score 2):

`onFormSubmit` is an arrow function, it cannot be bound, unless it's transpiled to ES5, and relying on this would be a mistake.

A quick and dirty fix is to make it regular function:

```
export async function onFormSubmit (files,props) {
    this.setState(...
}
```

It may be awkward to rely on dynamic `this` in this situation, at this point it isn't any better than passing `this` as an argument.

Since the purpose of this function is to update the state, a cleaner way is to make it state [updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) factory:

```
export const onFormSubmit = (props) => prevState => {
  const { files } = prevState;
  return { /* new state */ };
}
```

which can be used like:

```
this.setState(onFormSubmit(this.props));
```

`files` is available on `prevState`. Using `this.state` together with `setState` is an antipattern because `setState` is asynchronous, this may lead to race conditions.

Or make it not responsible for updating the state if it's asynchronous, e.g. it returns a promise:

```
const newStateObj = await onFormSubmit(this.state.files, this.props);
this.setState(newStateObj);
```

If it's synchronous, the use of `this.state` won't be a good idea because of the reason mentioned above.

Comment: I've expanded the question adding your answer. In short, onFormSubmit is a complex function, I cannot turn it into an updater (if I'm understood well what you're saying here)

Comment: I see. Then it's likely should be like the last snippet suggests. Use promises in onFormSubmit and use  this.setState outside of it. It's unclear why there should be multiple setState calls in option C. There's a chance that they are not needed. Options A and B smell badly.

Comment: The purpose of using a stateless function instead of having the code there in the component is to split the code in different files for clarity, since the file was too large. Maybe I should organize the code differently, but the main problem is that I don't know how to properly split code with React if components are not suitable since there's nothing to render in this case (only doing some calculations)

Comment: It's a good thing to have a separate function for design reasons but they also require a function not to be tightly coupled with a component (specifically `setState`). I assume that a function is supposed to produce new state asynchronously. So the last snippet from the answer is applicable. It's unclear why there are 2 `setState` calls in your `onFormSubmit`. If you can get rid of first one, it will be simpler. I cannot suggest anything more specific without seeing how the thing works. Consider updating the question with more detailed code that gives an idea what's the deal with 2 `setState`s

Answer (score 1):

Call bind BEFORE the function call like such:

```
onFormSubmit.bind(this)(this.state.files, this.props)
```

Comment: It only works if not using the arrow functions on the definition of `onFormSubmit` function (added in the question)